# Add TabItems to an existing TabControl WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have `TabControl` that has already define some `TabItems` on `XAML`. I need to create new `TabItems` and add to it.

If I use `ItemSource` I get an exception `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.`

The solution I have found so far is to create those `TabItems` I have already defined on `XAML` but programmatically on the ViewModel, so I can created the others I really need, but doesn't seems to be a good solution.

Other solution would be to add the `TabControl` as a property and use the Code-Behind to bind it to the ViewModel, which I would like to avoid.

So, I'm  just wondering if there is a way to do this only with `XAML` and MVVM.

Edit:

ItemSource attempt, which is working.

XAML:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderThickness="0.5"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Model.TabItems, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <!--<TabControl.Items>
    </TabControl.Items>-->
</TabControl>
```

Model

`public ObservableCollection<TabItem> TabItems {get;set;}`

VM

```
TabItem tabItem = new TabItem { Content = new DetailedViewModel((MyObject)inCommandParameter) };
Model.TabItems.Add(tabItem);
```

Comment: The only way I can think with using `XAML` is that you set all your `TabItems` but you set their Visibility to `false`, and then when you need them you show them.
And if you are using `ItemSource`, well then I suggest you to check [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776766/why-is-this-xaml-getting-the-error-items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using)

Comment: Yep, with `ItemSource` its working, but I have some fix `TabItem`'s and others that I have to create dynamically, it makes sense for me to create on `XAML` the fixed ones, and the others in the ViewModel, but seems that I will have to do "everything or nothing" style. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you show us the XAML for the `ItemsSource` attempt?

Comment: Sure @XAMlMAX, but like I said, that is working fine. The problem is when I mix both, definition of TabItems on `XAML` and in the VM

Comment: Have you heard of `CompositeCollection` and `CollectionViewSource`?

Comment: BTW if you store `TabItem`'s in your `ViewModel` this is **NOT** MVVVM.

Comment: You are right, my mistake on the edit, `TabItem`'s are stored on the Model.

And not, I have not heard before about the `CompositeCollection`, but according to the MSDN I could use it to mix both list?

Comment: Using `CompositeCollection` I get an exception, and I'm not able to make it work with `CollectionViewSource`. Do you have an example @XAMlMAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing here is **NOT** MvvM. Idea behind it is to keep parts of the app separate, i.e. Model should NOT return any UI elements. If you want to use this with any other UI framework for example `WinForms` then it will fail and will require additional work.
What you need is something like this, bear in mind that this is an example and you will need to modify this to comply with your requirements.
Model class:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Profile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static int I { get; set; } = 2;
    }
}
```

After this you will need the ViewModel:

```
namespace VM
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            ProfilesCollection = new List<Profile>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                ProfilesCollection.Add(new Profile() {Name = $"Name {i}"});
            }
        }

        private List<Profile> profilesCollection;   

        public List<Profile> ProfilesCollection
        {
            get { return profilesCollection; }
            set { profilesCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we have base to work with. After that I assume you know how to add the relevant references in your xaml, but this might be seen by other people so I will include it anyway.
Here is a complete MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:SO_app.Converters"
    xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:SO_app.Validation"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Model;assembly=Model"//reference to my model
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="452.762" Width="525" Closing="Window_Closing">
<!-- d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" -->
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ProfilesCollection}" x:Key="profiles"/> // this corresponds to our collection in VM
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>//Data Context of the Window
</Window.DataContext>

<Window.Background>
    <VisualBrush>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Fill="ForestGreen"></Rectangle>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Background>
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Profile}">//this data template will be used by the TabControl
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <TabItem Header="First Item"/>
            <TabItem Header="SecondItem"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource profiles}}"/>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
</TabControl>
```

If you want to add more items then just use Command which would be implemented in VM and just add `profile` to it and enjoy the show.

Comment: I will give a try, but, based on your first sentence, _What you are doing here is NOT MvvM. Idea behind it is to keep parts of the app separate, i.e. Model should NOT return any UI elements._ I have read that is the model who has the properties of the UI and the ViewModel who manages those properties, other way, and if I understand you, if the properties of the UI goes on the ViewModel, then what goes in the Model?

Comment: Model is your database representation. So whatever you use to store the data. In my case it's usually MS SQL. I would class the Entity Framework classes as a Model. Now these classes have properties on them that are used by the UI, namely `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>`.

Comment: Your answer works as expected.
Regarding your last comment, you will move the `ObservableCollection<TabItem>` I have now in the Model to the ViewModel, right? And in case I need the item in the Model use a binding SelectedItem or something like that.

Comment: You should have `ObservableCollection` but **NOT** with `TabItem`. Replace `TabItem` with you model class (look at my answer) that is how it will work. The `DataTemplate` will be used to present the content in UI, you only supply data in Model and View Model, **NEVER UI ELEMENTS**.

Comment: Understood, the only problem is that the `Content` of the `TabItem` is a `UserControl` ViewModel, I guess I have to create a class where I put the VM as a property and bind it like in your example, but instead `TextBlock.Text` use `ContentPresenter.Content`.