# Trigger a PropertyChanged event the moment a checkbox in a DataGrid row is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DataGrid that looks like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="Users" ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Name="SelectAllUsers" 
                          Checked="SelectAllUsers_Checked" 
                          Unchecked="SelectAllUsers_Unchecked"/>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="SelectUser" 
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                              Checked="SelectUser_Checked" 
                              Unchecked="SelectUser_Unchecked"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="UserName" 
                            Binding="{Binding UserName}" 
                            Header="Name" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It is currently data-bound to a `BindingList` in the ViewModel:

```
class SecurityDialogViewModel
{
    public BindingList<User> Users { get; set; }
```

`User` is a DTO with an `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation (Fody.PropertyChanged):

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

`SelectAllUsers_Checked` has some code in the ViewModel that sets all of the checkboxes to true, and then calls a method in the ViewModel to perform some magic based on the checkbox selections in the Users BindingList collection (which are now all checked):

```
private void SelectAllUsers_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SelectAll(Users, true);
    (DataContext as MyViewModel).PerformMagic();
}

private void SelectAll(DataGrid dataGrid, bool value)
{
    foreach (dynamic d in dataGrid.ItemsSource)
    {
        d.IsSelected = value;
    }
}
```

This all works perfectly fine.  However, checking a single user does not.  The underlying binding list apparently remains unmodified:

```
private void SelectUser_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (DataContext as MyViewModel).PerformMagic(); // Doesn't execute
}
```

I thought I knew why.  `BindingList` does not trigger a `PropertyChanged` event until you move off the record.  But unchecking another checkbox on a different row (thereby moving off the original record and supposedly triggering the `PropertyChanged` event) has no effect either.

**What I really need is a collection that will trigger a PropertyChanged event the moment one of the DataGrid row checkboxes is clicked.**

How would I go about doing that?  Can I subclass an `ObservableCollection` and capture one of its events?  Or do I need to write my own?  Perhaps I can simply hook an event on an existing `ObservableCollection` that currently isn't being observed?

Comment: It looks like you are manually triggering the property changed event by setting `IsSelected = value` in `SelectAll`. Have you tried creating a similar method for `SelectUser_Checked`? I think the only thing you would need is a way to determine which selection was checked.

Comment: @Sudsy1002: `IsSelected` is not being set directly.  SelectAll is checking all of the DataGrid  checkboxes in code-behind, and data binding is setting the underlying User collection records.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding, but from your code in `SelectAll`, you pass in `Users` as the datagrid. You then set each User.IsSelected in Users to true. Why can't you do the same, but only with the checked users, in a separate method, such as SelectOne, and then call SelectOne from `SelectUser_Checked` just as you call `SelectAll` from `SelectAllUsers_Checked`?

Comment: @Sudsy1002: Because I would be setting the checkbox in the click event handler, the coding equivalent of biting my own teeth.  It also causes an endless loop.  See my answer below.

Comment: You could also look into `CollectionViewSource`. Have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48662326/2029607). There is a lot more to the collection view source like sorting, filtering and grouping. All done in UI.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I did consider `CollectionViewSource` for filtering, but I needed better control than a Linq statement could provide.  Sorting by column clicked is already provided by the DataGrid.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the solution turned out to be much simpler than I thought it was going to be:

```
private void SelectUser_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = (sender as CheckBox).GetBindingExpression(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
    binding.UpdateSource(); // Triggers PropertyChanged Notification

    (DataContext as MyViewModel).PerformMagic();    
}
```

This also works:

```xml
<CheckBox 
      x:Name="SelectUser" 
      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

**Caveats**

`BindableList` has its own problems.

- You can't apply sorting to it from a `DataGrid`, which means that you have to [subclass it if you want this capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661195/datagridview-using-sortablebindinglist).
- It can cause memory leaks under certain conditions; specifically, `BindingList` doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` and will cause a memory leak if bound to a control's `ItemsSource` property.

Eventually I decided to use an `ObservableCollection` and do the event handling in code-behind instead of trying to rely on data-binding events.  It turned out to be simpler and easier to grasp, didn't require any special subclasses of collections, and I got the fine level of control that I wanted.

**Further Reading**
[The UpdateSourceTrigger property](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/the-update-source-trigger-property/)
[Sortable BindingList Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661356)
[Another Sortable BindingList Implementation](https://martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html)

Comment: As a note, the [`ToggleButton.IsChecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) property binds TwoWay by default. UpdateSourceTrigger should also be PropertyChanged by default.

Comment: @Clemens: The behavior changes if you remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger` portion.  It no longer triggers data binding when a checkbox is checked.