# Why do I get a DependencyProperty.UnsetValue when converting a value in a MultiBinding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, ivalueconverter

I have an extremely simple IMultiValueConverter that simply OR's two values. In the example below, I want to invert the first value using an equally simple boolean inverter.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiBoolToVis}">
    <Binding Path="ConditionA" Converter="{StaticResource boolInverter}"/>
    <Binding Path="ConditionB"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

and the inverter:

```
public class BoolInverterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            return !((bool)value);
        }
        return null;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

When I include the boolInverter, the first value in the MultiValueConverter becomes a "DependencyProperty.UnsetValue". There are no problems when I do not use the converter (other than not the logic I am aiming for, of course).

Am I missing something? Stepping through the debugger shows that the InverseBoolConverter is properly inverting the value I pass it, but that value is then not being 'sent' to the MultiValueConverter.

Comment: see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683863/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From MSDN:

UnsetValue is a sentinel value that is used for scenarios where the WPF property system is unable to determine a requested DependencyProperty  value. UnsetValue is used rather than null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), because null reference could be a valid property value, as well as a valid (and frequently used) DefaultValue.

Which means one of the following things:

- You use a template (`ControlTemplate` or `DataTemplate`), and the value does not have a DataSource set at the time of being Loaded. So it will hit your converter twice, first with the UnsetValue, second with the boolean value; so nothing to worry about;
- Your `Binding` is incorrect, meaning the Binding cannot determine a value, thus resulting in the UnsetValue.. You should propbably see a warning..

Also, you cannot combine Converters like you do.. So its probably that.

Remove the Converter in the inner Binding, and it should be fixed! :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really? So would I have to have a mirror property, "InverseConditionA", to do what I'm trying? Yuck!

Comment: Yeah, or expand your MultiValueConverter with parameters, to invert the first boolean?

Comment: How can I check whether a particular 'value' in converter has dependencyproperty.unsetvalue ? I mean if I want to cast the value to Int then it will throw an error like (Int32)value - as value is dependencyproperty.unsetvalue. anyidea?

Comment: Found my answer :) .. by using 'is' i can check.

Comment: The Output window displays information about all binding failures.

Comment: I just had the issue today when i made a control template but forgot to set binding for "Background" to "TemplateBinding Background". It shows the error at design time.

Comment: @Rohit I know I'm a few years late, but you can compare directly to the property.`if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) {// Do Stuff}` Any drawback to this approach?

Comment: @TylerStandishMan appreciate your response. I've moved on from WPF now. Hoping your response helps someone.

Comment: Maybe you can try convert to bool: `bool outTest; if (bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out outTest) { var a = (bool) value; .... } ` so DependencyProperty.UnsetValue won't be converted.

Answer (score 5):

Just in addition to all other answers, I usually add these lines to the beginning of `Convert` method:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(x => x == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue))
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        ...

    }
```

to make sure that none of the values is unset (that usually happens with `DataGrid` with `CanUserAddRows="True"`).

Answer (score 0):

If occuring in a datagrid try setting CanUserAddRows="False"