# Fill DataGrid Column from array

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to fill column in DataGrid from List(in one cell I want to have objects from my collection). How can I do this? Or maybe it's impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Bind your List to DataGrid ItemsSource:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" />
```

DataGrid will load objects from your collection. You can modify the columns using DataGridTemplateColumn.

View an example here:
[WPF DataGrid Control](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)

Comment: Yes, it's right. This question can be useful for prevention errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683863/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource.