# WPF - Binding in ListView's ItemsSource cannot be a List

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF application that I try to code using MVVM.The goal is to make something like a notification center, that lists different types of data.

To do this, I want to fill a ListView on the main page with different ViewModels. One ViewModel for each type of data.

The problem is:
When I put a (not a list) ViewModel in my ListView, it works fine. But if I put a list in my ListView, the program crashes on startup. I need the ListView to take a list (ObservableCollection perhaps) of mixed ViewModels.

I receive the error “Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.” at a seemingly random location in my code. Completely removing the code where the exception appears just causes it to show somewhere else.

I have the following:

**C#:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private List<IPageViewModel> _items;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _items = new List<IPageViewModel>
        {
            new StatusViewModel(),
            new SettingsViewModel(),
            new OverviewViewModel()
        };
    }

    public List<IPageViewModel> Items => _items ?? (_items = newList<IPageViewModel>());
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="InfoCenter.Views.Main.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:test="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views.Test"
        xmlns:main="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views.Main"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views"
        xmlns:settings="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views.Settings"
        xmlns:status="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views.Status"
        xmlns:overview="clr-namespace:InfoCenter.Views.Overview"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="500" 
        MaxWidth="1920"
        WindowStyle="None" Loaded="MainViewLoaded" 
        SizeChanged="MainViewSizeChanged"
        PreviewKeyDown="OnPreviewKeyDown"
        GotFocus="OnGotFocus"
        Closing="OnClosing"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance main:MainViewModel}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type overview:OverviewViewModel}">
            <overview:OverviewView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type status:StatusViewModel}">
            <status:StatusView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type settings:SettingsViewModel}">
            <settings:SettingsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="24" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Minimize" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <Image Source="/Resources/arrow-down-1.png"></Image>
        </Button>

        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Items.Header}" />
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>

        </ListView>

        <StatusBar FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="{Binding ConnectionIcon}" />
        </StatusBar>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I really hope that you can help. I have been trying to fix it the whole day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put *one thing* in the `ListView` contents here: A `Grid` control. Don't do that. There are two ways to populate a ListView in XAML: Bind `ItemsSource` *or* put items inside the content of the `ListView` element. You can't do both, and you did both, so it threw an exception.

Here's the ItemsSource version.

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    />
```

I'm not certain what that `Grid` is for; you may have to find somewhere else to put it.

But my guess is that want it to be used to display the items. We can do that by making it into an `ItemTemplate`. I'm a little confused by it, though: What is `Items.Header`? `Items` is a List, which has no `Header` property. Does `IPageViewModel` have a `Header` property? For the moment I'll assume that's the case; let me know if I'm mistaken.

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Content="{Binding Header}" 
                    />
                <ContentControl 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="0" 
                    Content="{Binding}" 
                    />
            </Grid>
        <DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Yes, IPageViewModel has a Header property, and I wanted to use the grid to show the items in a certain way.
Your ItemTemplate solution did the job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error I would recommend to change your XAML as was mentioned earlier in ["Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683863/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource)

Try this XAML:

```
     <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" PreviewMouseWheel="OnPreviewMouseWheel" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
         <ListView.View>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Path=Items.Header}" />
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding}" />
            </Grid>
       </ListView.View>
     </ListView>
```

Hope it will be helpful!

Comment: This isn't valid XML.