# Adding a new item to the combobox item source throw the following exception "'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to bind a list of strings to my combo box. But when I add a new item to the list or read items from the file, I receive Exception that Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource. Remember that I need to put a button at the end of the Combobox. what can be the issue?

my **Xaml** code

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Text="Category">
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Categories}" />
                   <ComboBoxItem>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource styleTextButton}"
                                    Content="New Category"
                                    Command="{Binding AddNewCategoryCommand}" 
                                    Width="235"/>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
```

I have read [“Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683863/items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource) but it did not help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* add an item directly to the `Items` property after you have set the `ItemsSource` property.

If you use an `ItemsSource`, you should add a new item to the source collection, i.e. `Categories` in this case.

Either you use an `ItemsSource` or you don't. It's one way or the other but not both.

Comment: The XAML code for what? How are you currently adding an item when you get the exception?